# issue outside of code is causing problems inside code

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Excel is giving me problems with the following code

```
'Updates the "5001 Prog" sheet with the new data
    prog.Range("C12").Value = (y & "'' Ream")

    prog.Range("D12").Value = count * 31.5

    prog.Range("E12").Value = daily * 31.5
```

It does not matter what I change after the "=" sign, or before the "=" sign I get the

"Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error"

What could cause this error outside of the VBA code?

Comment: do `prog.Range("C12").Select` and check if the expected cell is selected. i suspect that _prog_ is not a worksheet object

Comment: the issue "outside" may be a vba-error which is reset by doing a vba-reset... then all variables will be "forgotten" and `prog` isn't a pointer to a sheet anymore... or something similar...

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: Yes the sheet is protected, but there is code in the sub that unprotected it. I found that the problem was that I had "sheet" code that was running any time a cell would change on the worksheet and it would protect the sheet after the first line of code had ran. I specified the "sheet" code to only run when certain cells changed and the code above will now work. Thank you all for your help.